# Palo Alto and nfdump: No matched flows

Tags: netflow, palo-alto-networks

I am new to netflow so maybe I have the problem is about understanding, but I have not found references on what is happening.

I have a Palo Alto PA500 firewall and I am trying to extract netflow statistics to an Ubuntu box with nfdump.

I have installed nfdump and run nfcap without problems:

```
sudo apt-get install nfdump
nfcapd -E -T all  -p 9001 -l /tmp/nfcaptest
```

I have configured the Palo Alto as described in the documentation:

```
Device / Server Profiles / Netflow
    Add
        Name: nfserver
        Refresh:
            Minutes: 30
            Packets: 20
            Active Timeout (min): 5

            Name: nfserver
            IP: x.x.x.x
            Port: 9001
```

I have added the netflow server to all the interfaces and commited the changes.

I am seeing the traffic in the server with tcpdump.

```
12:51:33.848206 IP x.x.x.x.50705 > nfserver.9001: UDP, length 1369
```

nfcap is giving this output constantly:

```
Ident: 'none' Flows: 0, Packets: 0, Bytes: 0, Sequence Errors: 0, Bad Packets: 0
Total ignored packets: 0
File Block Header:
  NumBlocks     =           0
  Size          =           0
  id             =           2
```

I see that there is a nfcapd.xxx file every 5 minutes but when I try to read them I see no results.

```
#  nfdump -r nfcapd.current.7757
Date first seen          Event  XEvent Proto      Src IP Addr:Port          Dst IP Addr:Port     X-Src IP Addr:Port        X-Dst IP Addr:Port   In Byte Out Byte
No matched flows
```

What am I missing? Is the problem in the Fw (not sending the data) or in the server (not using it)?

UPDATE:
Looks like the problem is with nfcapd. I have opened the tcpdump capture with Whireshark and I can see all the netflow data is correctly received. For some reason nfcapd is ignoring/not receiving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Althought I have not yet found the final solution, there is a communications issue. I have reproduced the installation in a different environment and it works perfectly.

Tha main issue is that nfcapd is not receiving the traffic. Looks like some process in the system is intercepting it.